# Enabling Minification/Concatenation on 6.3 version of MobileFirst CLI?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

We are trying to enable the Minficiation/Concatenation feature in MobileFirst 6.3 via the command line for use in our build servers. However, we cannot find the correct options to select to get it do that task.

We have been able to successfully perform this task using the IDE, but this is not a viable option with the build server. We are using identical build-settings.xml files between the Eclipse IDE build and the CLI build.

I have heard that there is a method for accomplishing this through editing the ANT script of the CLI. Does anyone know where this is located in the CLI, and how I would go about doing this?

Comment: You have "heard"? heard this where?

Comment: We had some initial contact with IBM about this, but we couldn't get a clear answer about this being a guaranteed fix from them on 6.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optimization feature that enables minification and/or concatenation in Hybrid applications is not available in the MobileFirst 6.3 CLI tool - only in MobileFirst Studio.

This is, however, possible using the MobileFirst CLI tool in v7.0. You can find the user documentation for this feature here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_optimize_app_cli.html

Comment: Is there a way to manually get worklight.js and wljq.js minified before the build process then? We need to find a workaround for this, as we're stuck on 6.3 and those two files are huge.

Comment: Those are two files I would be hesitant to touch... and you probably mean minify Post build process. You can use Google Closure: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/obfuscating_javascript_code?lang=en